# JavaScript function which acts on itself to extend itself with another object

Tags: javascript

I am sure there is a name for what I am trying to do and I am sure this has been asked before, but I am struggling to find an existing answer - probably because I am not searching for the correct term. I have a JavaScript function called `extend()` which is similar to `Object.assign()` to merge Objects together - I don't have access to `Object.assign` in my current implementation.

```
function extend(target) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    if (typeof arguments[i] !== 'object') {
      continue;
    }
    for (var j in arguments[i]) {
      if (arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
        if (typeof arguments[i][j] === 'object') {
          target[j] = extend({}, target[j], arguments[i][j]);
        }
        else if (!target.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
          target[j] = arguments[i][j];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return target;
}
```

This works fine if I call it using `extend(target, defaults)` which will merge the contents of `defaults` into `target` without overwriting any existing keys in `target` (unless they are Objects and then they are merged).

I am looking for a way to actually call this using `target.extend(defaults)`, so the first `target` parameter to `extend` is actually implied as `this`. I have tried to rewrite the function by replacing `target` with `this`, but it doesn't have the desired result (I think the way I have changed the recursion is wrong).

```
target.extend = function() {
   ...
   this[j] = this.extend(this[j], arguments[i][j]);
   ...
   return this;
};
```

Any pointers (or references to existing answers) would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you have any access to `Object.assign({})`? Why not use a polyfill if you don't? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill Reinventing the wheel is an unnecessary stretch

Comment: Java's ScriptEngine which doesn't seem to support `Object.assign`

Comment: Which is why we're going to use a polyfill, because older version of JS does not support it. @chrixm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the function to `Object.prototype` to achieve the functionality you're looking for:

```js
Object.defineProperty(
  Object.prototype,
  'extend',
  {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function() {
      const target = this;
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] !== 'object') {
          continue;
        }
        for (var j in arguments[i]) {
          if (arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
            if (typeof arguments[i][j] === 'object') {
              target[j] = extend({}, target[j], arguments[i][j]);
            }
            else if (!target.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
              target[j] = arguments[i][j];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return target;
    }
  }
);


const obj = { foo: 'foo' };
obj.extend({ bar: 'bar' });
console.log(obj);
```

Or, cleaning up the code a bunch:

```js
Object.defineProperty(
  Object.prototype,
  'extend',
  {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(...args) {
      const target = this;
      for (const arg of args) {
        for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(arg)) {
          if (typeof val === 'object') extend(target[key], val);
          else target[key] = val;
        }
      }
    }
  }
);


const obj = { foo: 'foo' };
obj.extend({ bar: 'bar' });
console.log(obj);
```

But this is a *bad idea*, because it can result in name collisions and confusing code. What if there's an object like

```
const obj = { extend: true };
```

What does `obj.extend` do then? (It'll refer to the own property, but this isn't something a script-writer should have to worry about. Better to have a standalone function.)

This is exactly the same reason why many of the Object helper methods exist on the `Object` *constructor*, and not on `Object.prototype`. For example, you call `Object.assign`, or `Object.defineProperty`, *not* `obj.assign` or `obj.defineProperty`.

If you want this functionality only on certain objects, you can avoid the prototype pollution by calling `Object.defineProperty` on those objects:

```js
const addExtend = obj => {
  Object.defineProperty(
    obj,
    'extend',
    {
      enumerable: false,
      value: function(...args) {
        const target = this;
        for (const arg of args) {
          for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(arg)) {
            if (typeof val === 'object') extend(target[key], val);
            else target[key] = val;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  );
};

const obj = { foo: 'foo' };
addExtend(obj);
obj.extend({ bar: 'bar' });
console.log(obj);
```

Or, if you have control over where the object is created, you can use `Object.create` so that `extend` is a method inherited from the prototype:

```js
const objExtendProto = {};
Object.defineProperty(
  objExtendProto,
  'extend',
  {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(...args) {
      const target = this;
      for (const arg of args) {
        for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(arg)) {
          if (typeof val === 'object') extend(target[key], val);
          else target[key] = val;
        }
      }
    }
  }
);

const obj = Object.create(objExtendProto);
obj.foo = 'foo';
obj.extend({ bar: 'bar' });
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: For this reason I didn't want to use `Object.prototype`, but only define it against a specific Object which I want to be able to use this `extend` functionality.

Comment: @chrixm but specifically adding a `target.extend` on a target object will create name collisions as @CertainPerformance has explained. It doesn't matter whether you use Object.prototype or not

Answer (score 1):

Like @CertainPerformance has pointed out, what you're looking for will still create name collisions. But this is exactly what you wanted. You wanted to add a custom `extend` method in your target object right, then that's what we will do.

Explanation in comments

```js
function extend() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) { //loop through arguments
        for (k in arguments[i]) { //loop argument props
            if (typeof arguments[i][k] === 'object') {
              this[k].extend = this.extend; //attach extend function to object prop
              this[k].extend(arguments[i][k]) //execute extend recursively
            }
            else this[k] = this[k] || arguments[i][k]; //assign property to target while avoiding overwriting target object
        }
    }

    delete this.extend; //delete extend method
    return this; //return target object OR Object.create(this) to avoid mutating
}


//test

const trgt = { a: { a1: 2 }, b: 3, c: 5 };
const defaults = { b: 2, a: { a2: 1, a1: 55 }, d: 10 };

trgt.extend = extend; //assign extend method to target object

const result = trgt.extend(defaults); //execute
console.log(result);
```